# Why does `context.go` define and implement the `Context` interface?

Tags: go

The [`interfaces portion of Golang CodeReviewComments`](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CodeReviewComments#interfaces) states:

> Go interfaces *generally* belong in the package that uses values of the interface type, not the package that implements those values. The implementing package should return concrete (usually pointer or struct) types: that way, new methods can be added to implementations without requiring extensive refactoring.

Yet, Go's [`context.go`](https://golang.org/src/context/context.go) module both defines the `Context` interface and implements it for `type emptyCtx int` and `type cancelCtx struct`.

Note, the portion listed above says they "generally" belong in the package that uses values of the interface type — so I understand that this is not a strict rule.

However, I am curious as to what the criteria is that makes it OK for them to do this in the `context` package.

Also, this assumes `CodeReviewComments` is a canonical resource for Go code reviews and style guide.

Comment: See the With* functions in the package.  The package uses values of the interface type `Context`.

Comment: The function signature explains why they define the interface, but the part that was confusing to me was why they implemented it. However, after looking at it again, I just noticed that they [return a concrete type that implements the interface](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/context/context.go#L533). So, maybe that is why they implement it in the module?

Comment: `emptyCtx` and `cancelCtx` are unexported types that are meant to back up basic functionality offered by the package, e.g. `context.TODO()` and `context.Background()`. It wouldn’t make sense to place them in another package because then they would have to be exported to be used in `context` package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Defining implementations of an interface in the same package is actually pretty common, especially when implementing a [strategy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) or [chain of responsibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern)(like context).

Take the [net](https://pkg.go.dev/net) package for example, it defines the `Listener` interface, but also `TCPListener`, `UDPListener`, and `UnixListener`. In this case it would be illogical to place the functionality in another package.

The [io](https://pkg.go.dev/io) package does a similar thing with the readers and writers.

Another handy pattern is to define a function alias for interfaces which only have 1 function. Like how [HandlerFunc](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http@go1.17.3#HandlerFunc) implements [Handler](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http@go1.17.3#Handler), allowing users to cast closures as HandlerFunc so they don't have to define their own type, which is much more work.

Comment: This is a great explanation, especially linking it with design patterns. I will into them (and how they work in Go) more. Thanks!